# Firefox page sometimes loads forever, how to determine cause?

Tags: debugging, firefox, html

Pages on my website sometimes load indefinitely (shows the circular blue loading animation in the tab, and "Waiting for example.com..." in the status at the bottom) in Firefox. Usually they finish loading very quickly.

Since I can't predict when it will have one of these episodes, and Firefox requires you to refresh the page in order to use the Network tool, how can I determine the cause of this on the rare occasions I see it?

I'm not sure if it is because JavaScript is running or a request for another file hasn't been answered.

This may happen in other browsers, but I generally only use Firefox unless the QA person I work with tells me there is a browser specific issue.

Comment: I made a little test page with an infinite loop to make sure I have the unresponsive script warning activated, and I do, so that doesn't seem to be what's causing this problem.

Comment: Maybe the question should be, "how can I know which file Firefox is waiting to receive, what url it used to make that request, whether it was a GET or POST, etc.?"

Answer (score 0):

Generally, use the httpfox add-on, Firefox developer tools, and Firebug. Understand your server software and make sure errors are logged. Read the log.

If you can repro the error then you should be able to use a debugger with your server and find the section of code that is processing forever. Maybe there's an infinite loop. Maybe a lock has blocked execution. Maybe a ridiculous query was made to the database.

Otherwise, unless this unpredictable error is causing you to lose money or endanger people, ignore it.